# Is it possible to force download using URL? The file isn't in my Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mp3, html5-audio

I'm trying to create podcast pages.

I have mp3 file URL `https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/web/tcips9/Introverted.mp3`

and want to have a download button linked to the mp3 file URL, so when I click it, I want to download instead of opening a new web browser and play.

```
= link_to "Download", @podcast.episode_audio_url, download: "{@podcast.episode_audio_url}"
```

I tried above code and it's opening a new web browser and play.

How do I achieve my goal?  Please help,.

My controller

```
    class PodcastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_podcast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /podcasts
  # GET /podcasts.json
  def index
    @podcasts = Podcast.all
  end

  # GET /podcasts/1
  # GET /podcasts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /podcasts/new
  def new
    @podcast = Podcast.new
  end

  # GET /podcasts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /podcasts
  # POST /podcasts.json
  def create
    @podcast = Podcast.new(podcast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @podcast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @podcast, notice: 'Podcast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @podcast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @podcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /podcasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /podcasts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @podcast.update(podcast_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @podcast, notice: 'Podcast was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @podcast }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @podcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /podcasts/1
  # DELETE /podcasts/1.json
  def destroy
    @podcast.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to podcasts_url, notice: 'Podcast was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_podcast
      @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def podcast_params
      params.require(:podcast).permit(:episode_url, :episode_title, :episode_description, :episode_audio_url, :episode_number)
    end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how's your controller action look like?

Comment: have you tried linking it to a page inside your app? I mean, if you link to an external URL it most probably will open it as it is, maybe if you create a new route for downloads, `link_to "Dowload", dowload_podcast_path` and then write the download logic in the controller

Comment: @mr_sudaca I haven't touched anything after generating scaffold. I updated anyway.

Comment: @Fagundes I haven't tried that way.  Since my app isn't the original source, I need to bring it from the external site.   The podcast is first published on the Podbean website and then feed to the iTunes and Spotify.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you writing the download logic in a app controller. So in your routes you would have

```
get download_podcast, to: "downloads#podcast"
```

your controller would be

```
class DownloadsController
  def podcast
    send_file Podcast.find(params[:podcast_id]).episode_audio_url, type: "audio/mp3"
  end
end
```

and your view would link to this action with

```
link_to "Download", download_podcast_path(podcast_id: @podcast.id), target: "_blank"
```

Comment: Is this considered as the file is in my app?  I couldn't understand "download_podcast_path".

Comment: This is a helper that rails creates when you register a new route, like in the first snippet I sent with the `get download_podcast`. Basically your click in the download button will redirect to a page inside your app, but then this page has no content and only executes the `send_file` method to download from external source